# Typescript object value type according to object property name

Tags: typescript

If a file name ends with `.png`, `.jpg`, `.gif`, the file must have the `Uint8Array` type, otherwise it must be a `string`.

```js
const files: Files = {
  "assets/logo.png": new Uint8Array(2),
  "overview.txt": "This is a txt file",
  "src/index.js": "console.log('index')"
}

type Files = ?
```

What should `Files` be in the example here?

I tried:

```js
enum BinaryFile {
    PNG = ".png",
    JPG = ".jpg",
    GIF = ".gif"
}

type Files = {
    [P in string]: P extends `${string}${BinaryFile}` ? Uint8Array: string
}
```

Comment: You ask for a type named "Tree" but there isn't any tree involved. It is an object, not a tree. Maybe a map, still not a tree. If you cannot find the right type for that data structure then it probably contains fields that are not related and should not stay together. Also, you attempt to solve at compile time problems that may happen at runtime. If `files` is modified during the program execution, no matter how you define the `Tree` type, it cannot help (because at runtime there is only JavaScript, no TypeScript, no types, no nothing.)

Comment: There is no specific `Files` type that works this way. The "otherwise" part is impossible. See this question. You can write [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WzqeLm) to capture the first requirement, but the second requirement cannot be achieved. Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer or find a dupe target; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that TypeScript does not (yet?) have any way to express a type that is "any string except..."

For example, if you try this:

```js
type NotBanana = Exclude<string, 'banana'>;
```

...TypeScript will accept it, but `NotBanana` will just become an alias for the `string` type -- the exclusion is ignored.

As a consequence, it isn't possible to express a negative rule for `NOT *.png/jpg/gif` that is mutually exclusive with the positive rule for `*.png/jpg/gif`, which is what is required here.

As for what you *can* do, I think your best option would probably be to explicitly specify the text-based file extensions as well:

```js
type BinaryFileTypes = 'png' | 'jpg' | 'gif';
type TextFileTypes = 'txt' | 'js'; // add more as necessary

type Files = {
  [Key in `${string}.${BinaryFileTypes | TextFileTypes}`]: (
    Key extends `${string}.${BinaryFileTypes}` ? Uint8Array
    : Key extends `${string}.${TextFileTypes}` ? string
    : never
  );
};
```